# Proper way to remove other operating systems after installing ubuntu?

Tags: grub2, uninstall, gparted

My environment:

- **Linux mint** on */dev/sda2*
- **Ubuntu** on */dev/sda7*
- **Windows 7** on */dev/sda4 & /dev/sda5*

[click for gparted screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M0ac5.png)

I want to remove my first OS **Linux mint**. I don't want to waste time to get my environment back working after removing linux mint. Which is a proper way to remove it and keep my other OS working?

Is it safe to just remove it with gparted (right click on /dev/sda2 -> delete) and update-grub afterwards?

Comment: Yes, its ok to do what you stated. > `right click on /dev/sda2 -> delete and update-grub `

Comment: Is it totally risk free? In the past I had many problems to boot my system up

Comment: Which did you install first - MInt or Ubuntu?

Comment: Since, its Mint, thus, its perfectly safe as your current grub configuration file resides in Ubuntu and not in Mint and thus deleting mint won't cause any problem unless you have a separate partition for boot used commonly by Mint and Ubuntu.

Comment: @Raphael my first install was mint.

Comment: read my next comment.

Comment: @Raphael ok I'll try. Add you comment as answer and let me give you credits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what happens (if you do not have a seperate `/boot` partition used commonly by two Linux OSes):

1. First, you installed Mint, so, the grub configuration file and anything related to GRUB was installed in this partition.
2. But, after you installed Ubuntu, everything related to previous Mint GRUB was overwritten by the latest Ubuntu installation.

So, if you now, delete the older Mint partition, no harm will be caused to your GRUB as it is not the active one. Also, a `sudo update-grub` later will fix any other issue.

Comment: what about the free space? I want to resize my ubuntu but because of */dev/sda6* I can't. Check http://imgur.com/Cd30LYx

Comment: @abstraction - delete the unknown and then resize ubuntu, but to do that you need to get out of your ubuntu system and login to a live DVD as because you cannot edit the active OS partition.

Comment: Glad it worked!

Answer (score 1):

It is safe to delete mint's partition. But make sure you run 'grub-install' afterwards just to confirm that GRUB is properly installed in your Ubuntu partition. Run the following in a terminal:

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sda
sudo update-grub
```

And you're done.

Answer (score 0):

Log into your Ubuntu. Then go to Gparted. Right click on `/dev/sda2` and then Delete the partition.

If you want this free space to be used into both Ubuntu and Windows then format it into `NTFS` file system.

And if you want this free space only to be available into Ubuntu then format it into `ext4`.
Quit Gparted.

Open terminal from dash by pressing `Ctrl`+`Alt`+`T`

```
sudo update-grub
```