# Safest way to remove other installed OS

Tags: grub2, partitioning, boot-partition

This is my current configuration

```
Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1            2048 743215128 743213081 354.4G 83 Linux 
/dev/sda2       743217150 976771071 233553922 111.4G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5       964487168 976771071  12283904   5.9G 82 Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda6  *    743217152 744265727   1048576   512M ef EFI (FAT-12/16/32)
/dev/sda7       744267776 860537355 116269580  55.5G 83 Linux
/dev/sda8       860538880 964478975 103940096  49.6G 83 Linux
```

And here the explanation, yesterday I have changed my computer. All hardware is new, except the hard disk, where I have a working Ubuntu 18.04 (**/dev/sda1**)

When I tried to boot the computer, it gave some errors so I tried to fix it by booting with USB device

**/dev/sda7** refers to the first try, I installed a new Ubuntu alongside the old one, using free space in HD... Grub was not loading, so I made a second try, installing again a new Ubuntu alongside the others, using more free space. **/dev/sda8** refers to that second try

Later, I found a solution & I have been able to boot the old Ubuntu... so now I want to safely delete that 2 new installed Ubuntus

After reading this [Proper way to remove other operating systems after installing ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/711245/proper-way-to-remove-other-operating-systems-after-installing-ubuntu) I am not sure if just deleting that 2 partitions would be a good idea, as they are the most recent OS in the computer

Any tips?

Comment: Deleting them safe. After deletion run `update-grub` from sda1 Ubuntu to remove deleted installations from boot menu. In case you have some booting problems make live cd/usb before deletion, you may use it if something fail, to repair.

Comment: I suspect `update-grub` won't be enough; yes it'll update the grub menus to reflect the removed partitions, but if the soon-to-be-killed OSes owned the boot sector I suspect you'll need to ensure MBR points correct and I'd suggest also running `grub-install` (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing in the re-installing from a working system section).  @LeonidMew's advice was good, but adding `grub-install` won't create any problems and may be necessary in my opinion (*if your kept OS wasn't the last installed*)

Comment: Thanks... You should post this as answer, I will accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the comments finally I just deleted **/dev/sda7** & **/dev/sda8** partitions (in my case, with https://gparted.org/) and then

```
sudo update-grub
sudo grub-install /dev/sda
```